# Mesh Surface Distorting Material

Tags: materials

I'm applying a material which features a transparent PNG lying on top of another material.
For some reason, my material looks like this. how can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: If transparency is a problem, and you are using eevee, made sure the Blend Mode of the material (the one with transparency) is set to something other than _Opaque_ (Alpha blend is often a suitable fit). You can find the settings in the Material Properties tab (with the material selected).

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Thank you Chris. The transparency seems to be okay... it's just that the graphic shown above is all wavy and distorted. I'm trying to figure out why

Comment: Maybe UV map related? Have you unwrapped your mesh?

Comment: @ChristopherBennett I'm hitting the U hotkey but nothing appears.

Comment: Do you know how to properly UV unwrap an object?
Can you post a screenshot of the UV map?

Comment: It was in fact UV map related. Fixed it, thanks for the help @ChristopherBennett